# Which continuous functions that vanish at $\pm$ infinity are not square-integrable?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, mathematics

What is the condition for a continuous real-valued function which is zero at $\pm \infty$ to be not square-integrable?

By "not square-integrable" I mean functions $f(x)$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2 \,dx$ diverges.

One non-continuous example I was given is the Dirac delta function

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [\delta(x-x_0)]^2 \,dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{\epsilon \sqrt{\pi}}e^{\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{\epsilon^2}}\right]^2 \,dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\epsilon}\rightarrow\infty.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You already gave the answer of your question. A continuous real (or complex) valued function $f$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x) =0$ is not square integrable if $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\! \! dx \, |f(x)|^2$ does not exist (diverges).
2. Your "example" is misleading. The delta "function" is not a function but a distribution. The product $[\delta(x-x_0)]^2$ is undefined (even in the sense of distributions).
3. A simple example of  continuous real-valued functions with $\lim\limits_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x) =0$ but being not square integrable is the following: $f(x) = |x|^{-\alpha}$ for $|x|>1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $|x|\le1$, where $0 < \alpha \le 1/2$.